# setting a global matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, global, setting

I want to save the incoming data into an array that remember its previous array position
`test.py`

```
global data, in_data
data_hold = {}
data = 0

def start_input(atm_data):
   data_hold[data] = atm_data
```

When calling twice from other  module:

```
test.start_input (5)
test.start_input (6)
```

The error output is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to put `data = 0` inside the `start_input(atm_data)` module, but the data is input into

```
data_hold[0] = 5
data_hold[0] = 6
```

I want the output to be:

```
data_hold[0] = 5
data_hold[1] = 6, and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
data_hold = []

def start_input(atm_data):
    data_hold.append(atm_data)
```

Should work, without any `global` stuff.

But that being said, a module isn't a great replacement for a proper class, which is what it appears you want.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt respond

Answer (score 0):

```
data = 0
data_hold = {}
atm_data  = {}

def start_input(atm_data):
    global data
    data_hold[data] = atm_data
    data +=1

 testing:
 start_input(5)
 start_input(6)
 start_input(7)

 output:
 data_hold[0] = 5
 data_hold[1] = 6
 data_hold[2] = 7
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: I want to access the recent value of my variable 'data_hold' which keeps being modified by other module.